# Can't move my sprites after using pygame colliderect

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm a beginner at making games with python PyGame and I am trying to write a function to detect collision. Here is the function I currently have:

```
def collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
    rect_list = [h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4]
    for rectangle in rect_list:
        if rect.rect.colliderect(rectangle.rect):
            return True
    return False
```

This is the full code of my game_functions.py:

```
import pygame, sys, random

def collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
    rect_list = [h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4]
    for rectangle in rect_list:
        if rect.rect.colliderect(rectangle.rect):
            return True
    return False



def rect_movement(settings, event, rect, name, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                  h1w1_4):
    if settings.selected_block == str(name):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                                                   h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_x < 300:
                rect.img_x += 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1,
                                                                    h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_x > 0:
                rect.img_x -= 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_x += 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                                                  h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_y > 0:
                rect.img_y -= 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_y += 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1,
                                                                    h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_y < 200:
                rect.img_y += 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_y -= 75


def square_movement(settings, event, rect, name, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                    h1w1_4):
    if settings.selected_block == str(name):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                                                   h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_x < 100:
                rect.img_x += 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_x -= 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1,
                                                                    h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_x > 20:
                rect.img_x -= 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_x += 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                                                  h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_y > 50:
                rect.img_y -= 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_y += 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1,
                                                                    h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_y < 300:
                rect.img_y += 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_y -= 75
            else:
                print('You win!')


def sml_square_movement(settings, event, rect, name, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2,
                        h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
    if settings.selected_block == str(name):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            if rect.img_x < 200:
                rect.img_x += 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                                                   h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_x -= 75

        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            if rect.img_x > 20:
                rect.img_x -= 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_x += 75

        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            if rect.img_y > 50:
                rect.img_y -= 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_y += 75

        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            if rect.img_y < 300:
                rect.img_y += 75
                if collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                                       h1w1_4):
                    rect.img_y -= 75


def rect_h1_movement(settings, event, rect, name, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2,
                     h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
    if settings.selected_block == str(name):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                                                   h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_x < 150:
                rect.img_x += 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1,
                                                                    h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_x > 0:
                rect.img_x -= 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                                                  h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_y > 0:
                rect.img_y -= 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and not collision_detection(rect, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1,
                                                                    h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
            if rect.img_y < 300:
                rect.img_y += 75


def check_events(settings, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            settings.selected_block = random.choice(['h1w1_1', 'h1w1_2', 'h1w1_3',
                                                     'h1w1_4', 'h1w2_1', 'h2w1_1',
                                                     'h2w1_2', 'h2w1_3', 'h2w1_4',
                                                     'h2w2_1'])

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # h2w1_1 movement
            rect_movement(settings, event, h2w1_1, 'h2w1_1', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1,
                          h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h2w1_2 movement
            rect_movement(settings, event, h2w1_2, 'h2w1_2', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1,
                          h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h2w1_3 movement
            rect_movement(settings, event, h2w1_3, 'h2w1_3', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1,
                          h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h2w1_3 movement
            rect_movement(settings, event, h2w1_4, 'h2w1_4', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1,
                          h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h2w2 movement
            square_movement(settings, event, h2w2_1, 'h2w2_1', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1,
                            h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h1w2 movement
            rect_h1_movement(settings, event, h1w2_1, 'h1w2_1', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1,
                             h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h1w1_1 movement
            sml_square_movement(settings, event, h1w1_1, 'h1w1_1', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h1w1_2 movement
            sml_square_movement(settings, event, h1w1_2, 'h1w1_2', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h1w1_3 movement
            sml_square_movement(settings, event, h1w1_3, 'h1w1_3', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)

            # h1w1_4 movement
            sml_square_movement(settings, event, h1w1_4, 'h1w1_4', h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1,
                                h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)


def update_screen():
    pygame.display.flip()
```

My main program:

```
import pygame

from py_files.settings import Settings

# Shape imports
from py_files.h2w1_1 import rect2hw1_1
from py_files.h2w1_2 import rect2hw1_2
from py_files.h2w1_3 import rect2hw1_3
from py_files.h2w1_4 import rect2hw1_4
from py_files.h2w2_1 import rect2hw2_1
from py_files.h1w2_1 import rect1hw2_1
from py_files.h1w1_1 import rect1hw1_1
from py_files.h1w1_2 import rect1hw1_2
from py_files.h1w1_3 import rect1hw1_3
from py_files.h1w1_4 import rect1hw1_4

import py_files.game_functions as gf


def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    # Start classes
    settings = Settings()

    display = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.screen_width, settings.screen_height))
    h2w1_1 = rect2hw1_1(display)
    h2w1_2 = rect2hw1_2(display)
    h2w1_3 = rect2hw1_3(display)
    h2w1_4 = rect2hw1_4(display)
    h2w2_1 = rect2hw2_1(display)
    h1w2_1 = rect1hw2_1(display)
    h1w1_1 = rect1hw1_1(display)
    h1w1_2 = rect1hw1_2(display)
    h1w1_3 = rect1hw1_3(display)
    h1w1_4 = rect1hw1_4(display)

    while True:
        # Blit images
        h2w1_1.blitme()
        h2w1_2.blitme()
        h2w1_3.blitme()
        h2w1_4.blitme()
        h2w2_1.blitme()
        h1w2_1.blitme()
        h1w1_1.blitme()
        h1w1_2.blitme()
        h1w1_3.blitme()
        h1w1_4.blitme()

        # Updating
        gf.check_events(settings, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4)
        gf.update_screen()
        display.fill(settings.bg_color)


run_game()
```

And I have 10 separate programs for all the rectangles. Here is what one of them look like (for the other 9, I just changed the image and the self.x, self.y variables):

h1w1.py:

```
import pygame

class rect1hw1_1():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.img_x = 75
        self.img_y = 225

    def blitme(self):
        img = pygame.image.load('py_files/images/h1w1.png')
        self.screen.blit(img, (self.img_x, self.img_y))
        self.rect = img.get_rect()
```

And I also have an image for the default state of my game:
[image: The Game Image]

What this is supposed to do, is to check if the selected sprite (`rect` variable) collides with any of those other variable rectangles (`h2w1_1`, `h2w1_2`, `h2w1_3`, ...). But with this code, now, none of my sprites can move. Why is that? And how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"But with this code, now, none of my sprites can move. Why is that?"* - How do you use the function `collision_detection`?

Comment: Yes, I use it like `if collision_detection():`

Comment: That does not dxplain the behavior. You havt to show some code

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for telling me! I edited the question now, so it's more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pygame.Rect.collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) to test whether a rectangle collides with one of a list of rectangles:

```py
rect_list = [h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4]
if rect.rect.colliderect(tile_rects) >= 0:
    # [...]
```

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).

Create a rectangle with the new location and do the collision test. Only change the location if no collision is detected:

```py
def rect_movement(settings, event, rect, name, h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3,
                  h1w1_4):
    if settings.selected_block == str(name):
        
        testrect = rect.get_rect(topleft = (rect.img_x, rect.img_y))
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEF and testrect.x > 0:
            testrect.x -= 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGH and testrect.x < 300:
            testrect.x += 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and testrect.y > 0:
            testrect.y -= 75
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN  and testrect.y < 200:
            testrect.y += 75

        rect_list = [h2w1_1, h2w1_2, h2w1_3, h2w1_4, h2w2_1, h1w2_1, h1w1_1, h1w1_2, h1w1_3, h1w1_4]
        if not testrect.collidelist(rect_list):
            rect.img_x, rect.img_y = testrect.topleft
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!